# Passing arguments with a method in it. Java

Tags: java

Could you please explain what this approach of passing such an argument to the `addActionListener` method is? I understand that button variable of a `JButton` type is created and event listener is defined. It's not really clear for me the `addActionListener` argument, namely `actionPerformed` method definition in it. Where can I ready about such an approach? Thanks.

```
JButton button = new JButton("New button");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
});
```

Comment: To put it short (and possibly offensive from a Java fanboi's viewpoint): It's a hack around Java lacking the (imo pretty basic and) darn useful feature of functions as first-class citizens.

Comment: One day Java will have closures .... JDK 8 (2012) :P

Comment: I guess it will make it in Java 10, in the early 20s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening here is that `addActionListener` takes an object that `implements ActionListener` as a parameter.

You are creating an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) that implements the `ActionListener` interface and within it defining the method `actionPerformed` which is required by the `ActionListener` interface.

This anonymous class gets instantiated as an object and that object is passed into the `addActionListener` method.

Comment: Thanks. Is it considered to be a good approach or it is better to clearly define inner class which would implement ActionListener interface?

Comment: It is very commonplace (and in my mind clearer) to use an anonymous class for the `ActionListener` because it keeps what the button does in one place, but also because it is only going to be used once, in that particular place. You don't want a separate named inner class for every button you have cluttering up your namespace.

Comment: Though, in my opinion, it is a messy solution compared to other languages which have first class functions and closures/lambdas, which would allow you to simply define a block of code and pass that into the function rather than building an entire class around it. Though, as Java can't do this (yet) that is neither here nor there. Just something to keep in mind if you start looking into the ways other languages do things.

Comment: Reese, how long do you expect your anonymous class reference to be available?  http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/ clearly violates O'Reilly's copyright in North America (though possibly not in the Ukraine).

Comment: Hmm, didn't notice that, it was just the first result for 'anonymous classes java' on Google. The information was correct so I went with it. It would be worth noting that the same material is also available on [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ns2_oYQnfy4C&lpg=PP1&dq=Java%20in%20a%20Nutshell&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q&f=true). Do you think I should change the link to that one.

Comment: How do you know I'm from Ukraine? :)

Comment: He didn't, he was referring to the `.ua` ccTLD for the website I posted.

Answer (score 2):

On the `button.addActionListener()`, the implemented class is called an [anonymous inner class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class). This class only exists within your `addActionListener()` method, and it's not known to anyone else. Basically, you are creating an `ActionListener` (even though it's an interface) that's passed to the `addActionListener()`.

Since `ActionListener` is an interface, you will have to implement the `actionPerformed()` method. When an event happens to your `JButton`, the listener in your JButton is informed (through the `actionPerformed()` method) passing the event that occurred, `ActionEvent`. 
Just a further (extra) note From Wikipedia:

> Anonymous inner classes are also used
>   where the event handling code is only
>   used by one component and therefore
>   does not need a named reference.
>
> This avoids a large monolithic
>   [actionPerformed(ActionEvent)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed%28java.awt.event.ActionEvent%29)
>   method with multiple if-else branches
>   to identify the source of the event.
>   This type of code is often considered
>   messy and the inner class variations
>   are considered to be better in all
>   regards.

This is basically an [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (just an extra bonus answer).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally, you can pass a method as an argument.

```
Method method = clazz.getMethod("method-name", method-parameter.class);
yourObject.call(method);
```